# How to start inserting row after some specified number to MySql database using Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, csv, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Basically what i want to do is that,

I have CSV file containing 10,000 rows that i want to insert into the database . When i start my transformation i want to start inserting in database after 4500 rows .
So i want to skill number of rows that i specified .

How can i achieve that ?
Any help would be great.

Image Description : I simply create a transformation that read data from csv and write to database . I do not know which step will help me to achieve this .

Note : I have attached my simple transformation [image: I simply create a transformation that read data from csv and write to database . I do not know which step will help me to achieve this .]

Comment: What is the purpose of adding this image to your question ? Please visit [ask] to ask a [MCVE] question.

Comment: If data is fixed you can use filter row step and put condition of >=45,000

Comment: But i don't have any "id" related field , that i can use like "if(id > 45000)" . 
Can we compare the number of rows we read so we can directly compare that , like "if(no_of_row > 45000) start inserting"  .
Can i get that count ?

Comment: You can create ID, using add sequence step.

Comment: can you explain me little bit more ? Because i am new to pentaho

Comment: "CSV file Input" step, you can specify row number field name, use that as ID

Comment: Thanks man , That works fine . 
Thanks @WorkingHard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following kettle file , that solved my problem .
Thanks to  @WorkingHard..and @jxc [image: I used the Add Sequencer and Filter rows to achieve this]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a step that count the rows processed, but you can use the "[User Defined Java Class](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Class)" step to count the row number and delete the first 4500 with a code like this:

```
// This will be the counter.
Long rowCount;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    if (first) {
        rowCount = 0l;
        first=false;
    }

    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    // Increment of the counter.
    rowCount++;

    // Check ouf the counter. Doesn't output the current row if it's less than 4501.
    if (rowCount>4500l) {
        Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
        // Adds the row count to a stream field.
        get(Fields.Out, "Count").setValue(outputRow, rowCount);
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);
    }

    return true;
}
```